# Working In Background Mode in XMPP

Tags: ios, iphone, xmpp, xmppframework

I am Working On XMPP.
I want to get notification in background mode. 
And I implement this things also ,

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender socketWillConnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket
{
    // Tell the socket to stay around if the app goes to the background (only works on apps with the VoIP background flag set)
    [socket performBlock:^{
        [socket enableBackgroundingOnSocket];
    }];
}
```

in my code i set VOIP flag in background modes of app plist file. In this mode my app can run in the background completely.
But apple reject that way.

So. i think other way is APNS(Push Notification) but In my app huge chatting users then how can handle messges using Push Notification ?

And one more thing can i set silent audio file play in background mode and set background mode working ?
in this way any problem or regection problem from apple side ?

So, Give Me some proper idea and suggestion For this Question.

Thank x in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

**And one more thing can i set silent audio file play in background mode and set background mode working ? in this way any problem or rejection problem from apple side ?**

This way Apple is rejecting App.

To notify use about the received message you have to use local notification for background and foreground state of App and  use push notification for not running state of App.

To achieve your purpose use any background mode is not the solution.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

**how can handle messages using Push Notification ?**

You need to check if user is connected to XMPP server or not. If user is connected to XMPP go ahead via XMPP messaging , if user is not connected to XMPP , send push notification that will help user to appear online and receive messages.

**And one more thing can i set silent audio file play in background mode and set background mode working ? in this way any problem or rejection problem from apple side ?**

Yes apple will reject app (Intended to cheat Apple )

Comment: but VOIP flag is reject from apple side

Comment: you dont need to set voip flag if you are not using sip calling feature

Comment: means ? set only Localnotification from XMPP

Comment: If you have no calling feature then use xmpp + remote notification (push notification) .

Comment: means when app in background than work via APNS and in foreground than work as XMPP local notification ?

Comment: yes i want also Local Notification in foreground than work as Localnotification rght ?

Comment: but Bro. , XMPP Provide LocalNotification For display message and notification. so why we can;t use that ?

Comment: Yes when app in background then work via APNS and in foreground use  XMPP notification (normal messages)

Answer (score 0):

When your app background / kill, that time send webservice to server which can tell - you are offline.

Then after sever can send you Push notification all chat content.